# How to change connection string in app.config

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, connection-string, app-config

I have a program that generates reports by using DataTables created by TableAdapters. Now my client has a new database, and he wants to be able to switch between the new one and the old one. I found that I can do it by changing the connection string in the app.config, but I don't know how to do it during run time. Can you suggest me a way? 
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I don't know how to do it during run time

Don't. You can have *multiple* connection strings in the `app.config` and access each when needed.

Configuration:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="conn1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
       connectionString="..." />
  <add name="conn2" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
       connectionString="..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

In code:

```
var conn1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn1"];
var conn2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn2"];
```

Comment: Will that effect the TableAdapters? I know that when I create a TableAdapter I need to specify the connection it will be using. I know that I can have multiple connection strings, but how to switch between them so that that switch effects the entire application

Comment: @NDraskovic - You will need to decide for each which connection to use. If you abstract away the decision of which one to use to a class of its own, you will have a central point where to access the different connection strings.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, so I'll tell you my idea and please tell me if it's plausible: I can create TableAdapters that create the DataTables which hold the needed data. Now since these databases have identical schema's, I would only need to change the connection of the TableAdapter and it should fill the DataTable with data from the database I want. Can this be done and how would I do it?

Comment: @NDraskovic - "I would only need to change the connection of the TableAdapter". Correct. The code above shows how to have different connection strings in configuration and how to fetch them. It is up to you to decide how to pass these to your table adapters.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem, I know how to get the connection string, I don't know how to pass it to the TableAdapter.

Comment: @NDraskovic - That's a problem. You can't change the connection string of `TableAdapters`. Consider changing your design to use `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` in code (or use EF or nHibernate or other ORM to connect to the databases).

Comment: Hm yes that is a problem. Do you know a way in which I can switch to SQL commands and still fill the DataTables created by TableAdapters. The problem is that I use those DataTables to store data displayed in my reports, and if I use "hand-coded" datatables I don't know how to pass them to those reports? Do you have some idea how to do this

Comment: @NDraskovic - I don't. But you can always ask another question - someone else may have an answer.

Comment: OK well thanks for your help anyway, I'll mark your answer as the correct one

Answer (score 1):

You can define more than one connection strings like this:

```
<add name="Conn" connectionString="Data Source=PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NHIB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>-->
<add name="Conn1" connectionString="Data Source=WINSERVER;Initial Catalog=NHIB1;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

And after that you can use conn or conn1 based on your requirement..like:

```
SqlConnection con;
con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Conn"));  Or
con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Conn1"));
```

You can switch between them as below:

```
string connectionString = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal ? 
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString :
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn1"].ConnectionString;
yourDataContext = new YourApplicationDataContext(connectionString);
```

Comment: Why are you using `AppSettings` and not the dedicated `ConnectionStrings`?

Comment: I know I can use multiple connection strings, but the problem is how to switch between them. Please see the comments in Odeds answer, they will give you better view of what I have to do